# Does the number of classes in the target variable affect the accuracy of a classification model?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, classification, probability, multiclass-classification

From my own experience, I noticed that the accuracy of a classification model inversely changed with the number of classes in the target variable. That is, the more number of classes in the dependent variable, the lower the model's accuracy. I don't know whether that change was caused by the number of classes or by the imbalances between them (although oversampling technique did help improve the model's performance a bit). I assume that because a larger number of classes leads to a smaller difference of probabilities between them, thus it is harder for a model to "confidently" determine the exact class.

Is there a more concrete theoretical basis to explain the observation above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to understand what accuracy "means" wrt. the number of classes is by considering a random baseline. Tossing a coin gives you 1/K accuracy where K is the number of classes. So 50% for 2 classes, but just 10% for 10, and just 1% for 100.

This shows that "60%" accuracy "means more" if you have more classes: a binary classifier with 60% accuracy is almost random, but achieving 60% accuracy for 100 classes is godlike (assuming the classes are relatively balanced).

Comment: Very interesting to view accuracy in that way (wrt. number of classes), but it's hard to wrap my head around it. I assumed the godlike 60% accuracy for a 100 class classifier had the standard meaning (that is, the sum of correctly identified instances divided by the total number of observations)? If so, a binary classifier with 60% accuracy is as good as a 100 class classifier with the same accuracy value? Thanks.

Comment: The "godlikiness" comes from the question "how unlikely it is to be this good with random guessing". So think for example about relatiev improvement. To get in binary classification from random to 60% you need to improve by (60)/(50) = 120%; But with 100 classes (60) / 1 = 6000% ! You are 60x better than chance, while in binary case merely 1.2x better.

Comment: I agreed with your logical reasoning but I  don't have much knowledge in statistics so I can't tell - *not sure how to say this* - whether your explanation is similar to the logic of proving 1 = 2. To be sure I understand you correctly, you basically said that the higher number of classes in the target variable, it's logical for a classification model to have a lower accuracy? Thanks

Comment: I said that number of classes provides a base to understand how "good" specific accuracy is. And the more the classes, the harder it is to get high accuracy (and thus "better/less random" your model needs to be). And no, I am not "proving 1=2", I am explaining the most common mathematical model for statistical reasoning - how likely is your data result of chance (random luck).